# is there a way to find the number of steps in which scala performs evaluation strategy

Tags: scala

I am reading about Scala's evaluation strategies - like Call by Value.
so if I have the following code:

```
def doSomething(x:Int,y:Int) = x + x
```

Now if I call this function :

> doSomething(1+2,3+4)

The evaluation steps will be:

```
Step 1 :: doSomething(3,3+4)  
Step 2 :: doSomething(3,7)
Step 3 :: 3 + 3
Step 4 :: 6
```

Is there a way in scala that these evaluation steps can be printed - which will help novices like me to understand the evaluation steps and compare 'By value' and 'By name'

Comment: for the **constant value**, it's evaluated in compile time. so In runtime, there is steps to eval it.

Comment: You may inspect the tree with macro at compile time

Comment: What are "steps" 3 and 4???

Comment: @Dima - those are the final 'steps' where evaluation happens

Comment: @jilen thanks - will need to check 'macro' and 'tree' - dont know of these

Comment: @satishmarathe I just don't see where those "steps" came from, especially, seeing that the actual answer should be 10 ... 
I think, you are kinda overthinking this: the steps are (1) compute parameter values, (2) execute function. There isn't really much to "understand". Pass-by-name parameters are somewhat trickier, but only a little bit.

Comment: You can use `javap` to see generated bytecode, but it's harder to look at if you are a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. In your example, constants will be folded by the compiler, and since the JVM does not natively support call-by-name, the compiler will also transform by-name parameters into functions with no arguments. So to simplify the picture, just think of by-name parameters as being wrapped in a function:

`def doSomething(x: () => Int,y: () => Int) = x() + y()`

and the calls as

`doSomething(() => 3, () => 7)`.

Answer (score 0):

Such a tool likely doesn't exist for Scala because this lambda calculus style evaluation, while a useful tool for describing the semantics of the language, doesn't correspond to what's *actually* going on under the hood when the JVM evaluates the bytecode generated by the Scala compiler.